# Idling a Worker in Heroku, with Django

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I am using Django in Heroku, and in my site I send batch emails every month through Celery. Since I only use this worker once a month, I don't want to pay for it all the time. I can stop the worker using a `heroku scale workers=0` and scale it back up with `heroku scale workers=1`  manually before and after I send my emails.

However since other non-techinical staff will sending email from django as well, they can not run these commands. Can I stop a worker by executing a command from Python in my Heroku web process? I could execute any commands before sending email.

Comment: Did you succeed with what you are trying to do with the python api client? I tried it myself but couldnt get it to work. Created an issue here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py/issues/10

Comment: No, shortly after posting this question I moved my site off Heroku, so I didn't ever get to try it. I'll look at the bug report though, I am still interested

Comment: Oh it seems that someone else also posted an issue on it. https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py/issues/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with heroku.py see issues: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py/issues/10 and https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py/issues/4

I made a quick work around, which uses the http resource directly:

```
cloud = heroku.from_key(settings.HEROKU_APIKEY)    
cloud._http_resource(method='POST', 
   resource=('apps', 'appnane', 'ps', 'scale'), 
   data={'type': 'processname', 'qty': 1})

cloud._http_resource(method='POST', resource=('apps', 'appname', 'ps', 'scale'), data={'type': 'processname', 'qty': 0})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with heroku.py the python api client. Its available on PyPi with source available at https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py

You could also use the scheduler addon and have a command that is scheduled to run once a month to send out your emails, without having to scale up a process.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the python API client, it just what I was looking for! I don't want a scheduled task because it not necessarily every month regularly, just around that time frame.